# Condition for closed contour integral to equal 0

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

When you get a simple closed contour integral of the form:

$$\oint_C f(z)dz$$

can the integral equal $0$ even if it's *not* holomorphic at an interior point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, consider $$\int_{C(0,1)} \cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz.$$ The function is not holomorphic at $0$ but the residue is equal to $0$, hence the integral too.

Comment: and can we characterize that $f(z)$ is (or extends to an) holomorphic function on $|z| < 1$ by the fact that $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) z^k dz = 0$ for every $k$ ?

Comment: This only will allow you to state that $f$ is holomorphic at $0$ since the integral you wrote are the coefficients of the Laurent series at $0$.

Comment: yes I know, but we also get $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) (z-a)^k dz = 0$ since $(z-a)^k = \sum_{m=0}^k {m \choose k} (-a)^m z^{k-m}$

Comment: This seems right to me !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a simple example would be
$$
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^2}\,dz.
$$